# Flushing Session in Services

Tags: java, hibernate

Maybe it is my misunderstanding of Hibernate's Session flushing but I have been thinking in flushing my session inside my services but It does not feel ok to make things like this in a service:

```
public Object serviceMethod(Object model){

    //Do things with model
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

}
```

It feels wrong because my services will be knowing about my persistence mechanism.

So I have been thinking about making an aspect and using annotations so my code looks like this:

```
@FlushAfter
public Object serviceMethod(Model model){
    //Do things with model
}
```

Is this approach correct or am I doing things the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do that, as it's done automatically by the transaction interceptor already: by default, a Hibernate session is flushed automatically before the transaction commits. So if your service is transactional (and it should be, to work with Hibernate), the session will be flushed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

transaction interceptor/manager might decide to flush session() at the end of the transaction. Also remember that it may automatically flush session in the middle of the transaction if required. you don't have call flushsession explicitly. By the way, what is the reason to call flush session explicitly.
This [flush session in the middle of transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979644/flush-session-in-the-middle-of-transaction) - related question on this topic